# restoring git repository from bundle backup

Tags: git, backup, restore

i created backups of my git repository like in [How to backup a local Git repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2129214/backup-a-local-git-repository) proposed
with

```
git bundle create /tmp/foo-all --all
```

I can see all refs are in there, including a remote ref created by git-svn.
Now I can't figure out how to restore this bundle to a local repository again.
I am quite quite sure i've done it already once. I tried git-clone but that gives me a just a repository with my backup bundle as remote repo.

I also tried

```
git init
git bundle unbundle /tmp/foo --all
```

but this just lists all references...

Verifying the bundle gives:

```
$ git bundle verify $somewhere/foo.bundle 
The bundle contains 12 refs
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx refs/heads/xxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx refs/heads/xxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx refs/heads/xxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx refs/heads/xxxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx refs/heads/xxxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx refs/heads/xxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx refs/heads/xxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx refs/heads/master
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx refs/heads/xxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx refs/heads/xxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx refs/remotes/git-svn
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx HEAD
The bundle requires these 0 ref
$somewhere/foo.bundle is okay
```

Answer (score 54):

Short answer:

```
$ git bundle verify $somewhere/foo.bundle
$ git clone $somewhere/foo.bundle
Cloning into 'foo'...
Receiving objects: 100% (10133/10133), 82.03 MiB | 74.25 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (5436/5436), done.
$ cd foo
$ git status
...
```

Lazy Badger said this, but it's in the last paragraph.  :)

Answer (score 42):

I newer version of git is enough to do:

```
git clone bundle.file
```

the whole commands:

```
mkdir ~/git
cd ~/git
git clone /path/to/bundle.file
```

It will restore completely Your's git bare repository content (which will compile as it is normal source).
You don't need any other file. The bundle file is enough.

It is wise to always verify You bundle file before unbundle as follow:

```
git bundle verify /path/to/bundle.file
```

Answer (score 11):

Bundle contain not files, but **deltas**, you need **the base** in order to recreate the file content.
You have to clone first, unbundle later. Init instead of clone allowed only in case, where bundle requires 0 refs

Don't ignore `git bundle verify` before unbundling

[git-bundle(1) - Linux man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/git-bundle)

> Used to check that a bundle file is valid and will apply cleanly to
>   the current repository. This includes checks on the bundle format
>   itself as well as checking that the prerequisite commits exist and are
>   fully linked in the current repository. git bundle prints a list of
>   missing commits, if any, and exits with a non-zero status.

If you are creating the repository, then you can clone from the bundle as if it were a remote repository instead of creating an empty repository and then pulling or fetching objects from the bundle

Comment: @user1283719 `git clone foo.bundle`?

Comment: `git clone foo.bundle` makes a new repository with my backup bundle as remote repository as stated above. My local repository is beyond repair, so I would like to restore it from backup including the ability to use git-svn on its remote branch.

Comment: @user1283719 - just edit [remote "origin"] in config... Or use `git pull foo.bundle` instead of cloning

Comment: @user1283719 IIRC the svn info is lost on bundling. So you'd probably needed to backup the whole repo with the svn meta-information

Answer (score 5):

This should be the answer `git clone -b main <bundleName.bundle>`

Answer (score 2):

> I tried git-clone but that gives me a just a repository with my backup bundle as remote repo.

Bundle doesn't store original repository URL. You have to specify it manually:

```
git clone foo.bundle
cd foo
git remote set-url origin url-to-original-repository
```

Now you can fetch from and push to original repository.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> git bundle unbundle /tmp/foo --all
> ```
>
> but this just lists all references...

Actually, it now can do more than that:

Git 2.34 (Q4 2021) adds progress display to "[`git bundle unbundle`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/67fc02be54bc8f5e8abf381456f297e32440b88a/Documentation/git-bundle.txt)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-bundle))</sup>".

In addition to `git bundle verify` mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9808895/6309), it will show you at least what is going on.

See [commit d941cc4](https://github.com/git/git/commit/d941cc4c342f4feca6be2a410ac6dc56908880ec), [commit f46c46e](https://github.com/git/git/commit/f46c46e4f22506a01aa0033b37ef027d9e87585f), [commit 7366096](https://github.com/git/git/commit/7366096de9d3e4aee4b49dfdf0438a8636187a84) (05 Sep 2021), and [commit 0834257](https://github.com/git/git/commit/08342573792e9af79bf41b32c45ac471d25303bc) (26 Aug 2021) by [Ævar Arnfjörð Bjarmason (`avar`)](https://github.com/avar).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 67fc02b](https://github.com/git/git/commit/67fc02be54bc8f5e8abf381456f297e32440b88a), 20 Sep 2021)</sup>

> ### [`bundle`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/d941cc4c342f4feca6be2a410ac6dc56908880ec): show progress on "unbundle"
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Ævar Arnfjörð Bjarmason</sup>

> The "unbundle" command added in [2e0afaf](https://github.com/git/git/commit/2e0afafebd8c5a1a8cdddb0714073461229ecfef) ("Add git-bundle: move objects and references by archive", 2007-02-22, Git v1.5.1-rc1 -- [merge](https://github.com/git/git/commit/77b50ab009deab7f8eb703843a71ac7253b977c8)) did not show progress output, even though the underlying API learned how to show progress in [be042af](https://github.com/git/git/commit/be042aff24c8a17565934874f5d2eebd77ab2562) ("Teach progress eye-candy to `fetch_refs_from_bundle()`", 2011-09-18, Git v1.7.8-rc0 -- [merge](https://github.com/git/git/commit/9e3e789e70701beb25b3135d292edfbc99035701)).
>
> Now we'll show "Unbundling objects" using the new `--progress-title` option to[`git index-pack`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/d941cc4c342f4feca6be2a410ac6dc56908880ec/Documentation/git-index-pack.txt)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-index-pack))</sup>, to go with its existing "Receiving objects" and "Indexing objects" (which it shows when invoked with "`--stdin`", and with a pack file, respectively).
>
> Unlike "[`git bundle create`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/d941cc4c342f4feca6be2a410ac6dc56908880ec/Documentation/git-bundle.txt#L67)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-bundle#Documentation/git-bundle.txt-createoptionsltfilegtltgit-rev-list-argsgt))</sup> we don't handle "`--quiet`" here, nor "`--all-progress`" and "`--all-progress-implied`".
> Those are all specific to "create" (and "verify", in the case of "`--quiet`").
>
> The structure of the existing documentation is a bit unclear, e.g. the documentation for the "`--quiet`" option added in [79862b6](https://github.com/git/git/commit/79862b6b77c07b88ae1137fa602bf2046f979ad9) ("`bundle-create`: progress output control", 2019-11-10, Git v2.25.0-rc0 -- [merge](https://github.com/git/git/commit/ca5c8aa8e1cf837613801f26d22f63caea53484e) listed in [batch #2](https://github.com/git/git/commit/228f53135a4a41a37b6be8e4d6e2b6153db4a8ed)) only describes how it works for "`create`", and not for "`verify`".
> That and other issues in it should be fixed, but I'd like to avoid untangling that mess right now.
> Let's just support the standard "`--no-progress`" implicitly here, and leave cleaning up the general behavior of "[`git bundle`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/d941cc4c342f4feca6be2a410ac6dc56908880ec/Documentation/git-bundle.txt)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-bundle))</sup> for a later change.

`git bundle` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/d941cc4c342f4feca6be2a410ac6dc56908880ec/Documentation/git-bundle.txt#L16):

> ```
> 'git bundle' unbundle [--progress] <file> [<refname>...]
> ```