# Can I just physically copy my remote GIT repository to another machine with different OS

Tags: git, git-clone

At the moment my remote repository is on my development PC (Windows) on a separate drive. I want to move it to my Synology NAS box.

When I Google it, I can only find very complicated methods. Is there anything wrong if I
physically copy the directory structure over (I know it's a different OS, but surely the files should be the same).  I have "core.autocrlf" set to false.

Before someone tells me, it should be outside my house, I have a NAS box at my batch, and I intend to replicate information there.

Answer (score 2):

Git repos are self contained and copying will be fine; just make sure you're copying 'hidden' folders ('.git').

You could also just clone the repo to the new machine as each clone contains the full history.

From git's [About](https://git-scm.com/about/distributed):

> *Multiple Backups*
>
> This means that even if you're using a centralized workflow, every user essentially has a full backup of the main server. Each of these copies could be pushed up to replace the main server in the event of a crash or corruption. In effect, there is no single point of failure with Git unless there is only a single copy of the repository.

Answer (score 2):

The alternative to copy the full directory structure is a [`git bundle`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-bundle) (see "[Fully backup a git repo?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5578292/6309)").

That way, you have only *one* file to copy, that you can [clone from (yes, clone from a file)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70155310/6309) on the target system.

```bash
git clone foo.bundle
cd foo
git remote set-url origin url-to-original-repository
```