# GitLab start but stop right after

Tags: service, repository, bitbucket, gitlab

I have upgraded my version of `GitLab` to `5.3` and use `Nginx` instead of Apache. It worked one time and now I saw that GitLab stopped. So I try to re-start the service with this command **sudo service gitlab start** and watch what is happening with **htop**. I noticed that after 1 or 2 minutes the gitlab service stopped and I don't know why ...

I'm using a `AWS EC2` micro instance.

How can I retrieve all my repositories on GitLab and import them to BitBucket (or GitHub) ?

Thank you.

**Environment information**

```
$ sudo -u git -H bundle exec rake gitlab:env:info RAILS_ENV=production

System information
System:     Ubuntu 12.04
Current User:   git
Using RVM:  no
Ruby Version:   1.9.3p327
Gem Version:    1.8.23
Bundler Version:1.2.3
Rake Version:   10.0.4

GitLab information
Version:    5.3.0
Revision:   e1c473c
Directory:  /home/git/gitlab
DB Adapter: mysql2
URL:        https://domaine-name.com
HTTP Clone URL: https://domaine-name.com/some-project.git
SSH Clone URL:  git@domaine-name.com:some-project.git
Using LDAP: no
Using Omniauth: no

GitLab Shell
Version:    1.4.0
Repositories:   /home/git/repositories/
Hooks:      /home/git/gitlab-shell/hooks/
Git:        /usr/bin/git
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How can I retrieve all my repositories on GitLab and import them to BitBucket (or GitHub) ?

You can:

- log  on your AWS EC2 micro instance (like described in the [Bitnami stack](http://bitnami.com/stack/gitlab/cloud/amazon) or following this [installation blog post](http://blogs.perficient.com/multi-shoring/blog/2013/04/26/install-gitlab-on-amazon-ec2-cloud-server/))
- go to where the bare repos are stored (as mentioned in the [`gitlab.yml` config file](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/blob/master/config/gitlab.yml.example#L144-L147))
- make a bundle for each one (see [my answer on `git bundle`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1251717/6309)): that will generate *one* file per repo, which is easier to copy around
- copy those bundle files on your local pc
- clone those repos on your local pc (a bundle is an acceptable remote! `git clone mybundle` works)
- [add a remote](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9257901/6309) to a GitHub empty repo you have declared first
- push to GitHub