# Is there a way restore files from "repository.git"

Tags: git, gitlab

We have a git server on our local server. I want to backup these git repositories from server side directly copying "repositoryname.git" folders.

In case of a problem with a new server is it possible to recover files from these folder? I think the files stored as fractured on an Object folder on this .git folders. And not directly accessible from server.

Thank you.

Comment: If you can clone it from the server, you can also clone it from a copy of the server.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In order to backup bare repo from the server, you should avoid copying directly the `repositoryname.git` folder (which contains local config, including gitlab hooks), but rather do a git bundle (see [my answer on git bundle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1251713/backup-of-github-repo/1251717#1251717)).

```
 cd repositoryname.git
 git bundle create /tmp/repositoryname.bundle --all
```

That will generate *one* file, that you can easily copy around, and from which you can clone in order to restore that repo on another machine.

[The `.git/object` folder](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Internals-Git-Objects) will be re-populated once cloned, with the right objects.