# installing gitolite without cloning gitolite repo

Tags: git, gitolite

I'm trying to install gitolite on a redhat virtual machine. 
Now, the machine is **not connected to the internet**. Therefore, I can't run the 'clone' step of the standard installation.
I do have the source code on my machine, and when I run the 'install -ln' step - it throws:

```
fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
```

Which makes sense, because it's not a git repository (I don't understand why should it be a repository anyway).

I have also tried initializing a repo in the gitolite folder.. didn't help.

**How can I workaround the clone step?**

Answer (score 4):

You can:

- clone the sources on your machine
- [make a bundle out of that local repo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17529039/6309) => `gitolite.bundle`
- copy that *one* file on your server
- clone from that bundle

A bundle is a git repo you can clone from.
But it is also one file, which makes it convenient to copy around.

Comment: nice! didnt knew about this one.

Answer (score 2):

I wish people would ask on the mailing list.  I don't come here often, and if it weren't for some kind stranger pointing out to me that something has been posted here that may involve a code change I would never know.

Anyway the point here is that the error is misleading in its severity.  I'll eventually push a fix that will change that to something like "git describe failed; cannot deduce version number", because that is all that is happening there.  Everything else has worked as it should, despite this message.