# Restore individual repository from Gitlab backup file

Tags: git, gitlab, gitlab-7

I'm trying to restore only 1 repository from complete gitlab backup file .

I'm using gitlab-rake for backup my repositories .

Backup command :

```
sudo gitlab-rake gitlab:backup:create
```

How i can restore from this tar file only 1 repository ?

more Info :

Gitlab version : GitLab Enterprise Edition 7.13.5-ee

Thanks , 
Amit

Comment: there is a [comment](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/2397#note_2006913) in the forum that says, this is currently not possible - maybe [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28838451/restore-gitlab-backup-repository-bundle-file-with-all-branches) helps

Answer (score 0):

You can check this one: [backup restore](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/blob/master/doc/raketasks/backup_restore.md)

so you can use parameter before you backup the repository.

Comment: It is for total Gitlab backup, not for individual repository

Answer (score 0):

There is now an officially documented way/workaround to [restore only one or a few project(s) or group(s)](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/raketasks/backup_restore.html#restoring-only-one-or-a-few-projects-or-groups-from-a-backup).

Essentially: Restore the *full* `.tar` backup into a *temp* instance, then use the built-in ex- & import functions from there.