# GitLab server repository movement to gerrit

Tags: git, gitlab, gerrit

I have to move one repository from `Gitlab` server to `Gerrit` server along with the *history, branches and tags* etc.

Could you please suggest me the ways to do it.

Comment: It's just Git. You should be able to find plenty of information about how to mirror a repo in the internet. If you have a specific problem with that, please post another question later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Create the repository in Gerrit using the UI (or ask the Gerrit admin to do that)

2) Clone the Gitlab repository using the "--bare" option

```
git clone --bare GITLAB-URL
```

3) Add the Gerrit remote

```
cd REPO-NAME
git remote add gerrit GERRIT-URL
```

4) Push all commits, branches and tags to Gerrit

```
git push --all gerrit
git push --tags gerrit
```

5) Remove the temp repository

```
cd ..
rm -rf REPO-NAME
```

Comment: Dear Marcelo, Thank you very much for your kind support on time, I have successfully migrated all the repos from Gitlab to Local Git/Gerrit successfully.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever I need to move a repo (with its full history), I recommend [`git bundle`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-bundle): it creates only *one* file, which is easier to move/send/copy around.

You can then [clone your repo directly from the bundle file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28838777/6309).

That being said, as described in "[Restoring a Gitlab Bundle](http://blog.redbranch.net/2016/05/10/restoring-a-gitlab-bundle/)", the `gitlab-rake gitlab:backup:create` command does bundles for you (except they are tar files)
See more at "[Backing up and restoring GitLab](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/blob/master/doc/raketasks/backup_restore.md)".