# The way of migration from GitLab to GitHub Enterprise

Tags: github, migration, gitlab, github-enterprise

I'd like to migrate GitLab to GitHub. Of course, Git repo is easy to migrate. But other working items, such as Issue. Can I migrate all working items to GitHub Enterprise? If API is needed, please let me know the GitHub and GitLab APIs for the migration. If there is a tool, it is the best and helpful.

Best Regards,

Comment: Here, there is a good discussion about this issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23295548/export-a-repository-from-a-gitlab-server-to-another-gitlab-server

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I believe that is there a more efficient approach to solve this, but today we are trying Enterprise Edition and migrations projects individualy.

To export a full project, with Issues, MR history, ..., there is a section called Export Project.

Under project Settings > General > Export Project section with the following instructions:

> Export this project with all its related data in order to move your
>   project to a new GitLab instance. Once the export is finished, you can
>   import the file from the "New Project" page.
>
> Once the exported file is ready, you will receive a notification email
>   with a download link.
>
> The following items will be exported:
>
> ```
> Project and wiki repositories
> Project uploads
> Project configuration including web hooks and services
> Issues with comments, merge requests with diffs and comments, labels, milestones, snippets, and other project entities
> ```
>
> The following items will NOT be exported:
>
> ```
> Job traces and artifacts
> LFS objects
> Container registry images
> CI variables
> Any encrypted tokens
> ```

Now, I wanna learn if there is a global export for all projects.

Comment: Can you explain how you then imported that GitLab export into Github please?