# Transfer set of repositories from one gitlab group to another subgroup all at once

Tags: gitlab

How to transfer the repository or a whole set of repositories from one gitlab group to another subgroup. For example companyname.gitlab.com/team one/. To gitlab.com/team_first/phase1/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Export a repository from a Gitlab server to another Gitlab server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23295548/export-a-repository-from-a-gitlab-server-to-another-gitlab-server)

Comment: Check out the docs: https://gitlab.com/help/user/project/settings/import_export.md

Comment: @JonathonReinhart   I have more than 80 projects in a group which i want to move all at once. The export method works at individual project level.

Comment: That's a completely different question; one you should have asked first. You're not moving the entire server from one instance to another, are you?

Comment: It won't be easy to move just a group of projects. I would start looking into the GitLab API and scripting this process.

Answer (score 1):

The repositories/projects themselves still need to be exported by API, one by one.

But the new "Group Import/Export " feature from [GitLab 13.0 (May 2020)](https://about.gitlab.com/releases/2020/05/22/gitlab-13-0-released/#export-and-import-groups-in-the-ui) can be a welcome addition.

> ### Export and Import Groups in the UI
>
> Previously, users could only migrate groups by using the Export/Import API to create an Export file, then using the API a second time to upload the file to the target instance.
>
> As a first step toward a more frictionless solution, we have enabled Group Export in the GitLab UI.
> We plan to introduce similar Import functionality to the UI within the next few weeks.

See [documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/group/settings/import_export.html), [issue](https://about.gitlab.com/releases/2020/05/22/gitlab-13-0-released/) and [Epic](https://gitlab.com/groups/gitlab-org/-/epics/2888).

[image: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/group/settings/img/export_panel.png]

---

See [GitLab 14.2](https://about.gitlab.com/releases/2021/08/22/gitlab-14-2-released/#group-migration-achieves-parity-with-group-importexport) (August 2021)

> ### Group Migration achieves parity with group import/export
>
> The new [GitLab Migration](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/group/import/) feature can now migrate an entire group with all its subgroups and related data. The data migrated includes everything contained in [group exports](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/group/settings/import_export.html), making this a much easier way to migrate entire groups.
> The pre-existing group import/export is a two-step process that requires exporting a file and then importing it into another GitLab instance.
>
> Now, users can initiate a group migration with a single click. Migration also includes all the subgroups and their data, which previously required separate export and import processes for each subgroup.
>
> [image: https://about.gitlab.com/images/14_2/group_migration__parity_with_group_exportimport.png -- Group Migration achieves parity with group import/export]
>
> See [Documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/group/import/) and [Epic](https://gitlab.com/groups/gitlab-org/-/epics/4619).

---

See [GitLab 15.6](https://about.gitlab.com/releases/2022/11/22/gitlab-15-6-released/#associate-mrs-to-issues-when-migrating-groups-with-projects) (November 2022)

> ### Associate MRs to issues when migrating groups with projects
>
> When migrating groups using GitLab Migration, GitLab now preserves associations of imported merge requests to issues.
> This populates the **Related merge requests** section
> on the issue details page.
>
> [image: https://about.gitlab.com/images/15_6/gitlab_migration__associate_mrs_to_issues.png -- Associate MRs to issues when migrating groups with projects]
>
> See [Documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/group/import/index.html#migrated-project-items) and [Issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/267947).