# GIT equivalent to "svnrdump dump --incremental"

Tags: git, svn, bundle, clone, fetch

Is there an equivalent to "svnrdump dump --incremental" in GIT?

I am trying to incrementally backup several svn and git repos from a remote server to a local server but it seems that there is no direct way to "dump" a remote GIT repo.

Basically I perform either "**git fetch --all**" with already existing or "**git clone --mirror**" for all new repos followed by "**git bundle create --all**".

Is there any other/better solution than that?

Answer (score 1):

Once a [full bundle is created](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2129286/6309), you can create new *incremental* bundles.

I have mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23712022/6309) a [script to make incremental bundles](https://github.com/VonC/compileEverything/blob/1b01af253eb938efe8f04eb44f9e8af0d9633baa/sbin/save_bundles#L171-L173) (except once a wekk a full bundle) for all my repos.

```sh
echo "Create INCREMENTAL backup for '${name}' (previous was ${_dd}-${_dt}[${s}]" >> "${logf}"
echo "${nowd} Create INCREMENTAL backup for '${name}' (previous was ${_dd}-${_dt}[${s}]" >> "${logfb}"
git -C "${path}" bundle create "${bkp}/${name}-${nowd}-${describe}-incr.bundle" --since=${nbd}.days.ago --all
status=$?
```

The [OP](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3752299/user3752299) confirms [in the comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24286552/git-equivalent-to-svnrdump-dump-incremental/24287531?noredirect=1#comment37725468_24287531):

> I ended up doing a "`git bundle create`" after "`git fetch --all`" and/or "`git clone --mirror`"

Comment: Thanks for your hints, VonC! I ended up doing a "git bundle create" after "git fetch --all" and/or "git clone --mirror". Not sure but seemed to me the closest solution to my initial request...

Comment: @user3752299 Ok, I have included your conclusion in the answer for more visibility.

Answer (score 0):

This question is hilarious. Git (merely by virtue of being a DVCS) is by nature always an "incremental backup". One might say it is *always* "dumped". If a remote is set (i.e., you've cloned the remote repository), `git fetch` / `git pull` will bring it up to date.

If what you need is the repository to be packaged as a single file, I would recommend you take a look at a program called `tar`. If you're sure you want a full mirror (tracking the same remotes), to dump a git repo to a single file: `tar c .git > /path/to/my-repo-tarball.tar`.