# git create patch from unpushed commits

Tags: git, patch

I cannot push when working remotely, so I want to create a single patch from all the commits that have not yet been pushed on my develop branch to email it. How do I do that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Viewing Unpushed Git Commits](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2016901/viewing-unpushed-git-commits)

Comment: absolutely not, that thread only answers how to view unpushed commits, says nothing about creating a patch from them

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`git format-patch <commit-ish>` creates a patch file for every commit you made since the specified commit.

So, to export all your unpushed commits, simply put

```
git format-patch origin/master -o patches/
```

and all of them will be output into the `patches/` directory.

If you want to have a **single file**, add `--stdout`:

```
git format-patch origin/master --stdout > patches_$(date -I).patch
```

This will create a file named `patches_2014-10-03.patch` (or another date) with all your patches in it. **Beware:** `patch` or other simple patch applications cannot cope with the produced file. It will only work with `git am`.

---

Sidenote:
An easier (and more robust) thing to do might be to keep a copy of your repo on a thumbdrive or similiar. Then set up the thumbdrive as a remote (`git remote add thumb /media/thumbdrive`), push your commits to it (`git push thumb master`) and when back at your firm, pull from the drive and push to origin.

Comment: thank you, that was exactly what I was looking for
BTW, on OS X `date` turned out not to recognize the `-I` option, so I just called my patch `foo.patch`, happy days

Comment: Good to know, I was getting used to using `$(date -I)` everywhere :)

Answer (score 5):

Instead of [creating a patch](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2016901/6309), you could create a **[bundle](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1251717/6309)** (meaning a file representing a git repo, from which you will be able to pull).
In your case, an [incremental bundle](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23712022/6309) is needed.

```
git bundle create ../yourRepo.bundle" --since=x.days.ago --all
```

Replace `x` by then number of days you want to put in that bundle: don't be afraid to put "too mayn" days in that repo: someone cloning from your bundle will get only the new commits, not the one he/she already had in the local repo.

A bundle is a single file, like a patch, but can be used as a Git repo: easy to copy around and easy to use (as a regular Git repo).
If your only use is to complete a local repo with commits done from a remote repo (from which you couldn't push directly), this is easier than patches.