# Pushed to git bare repo and I can't pull changes from other machines

Tags: git, branch, dropbox, git-bare

I have a git repo on my Dropbox,

I am using Ubuntu,

I have a project which I've cloned via

```
git clone blablabla/Dropbox/blablabla.git
```

and I've pushed for like 500 times to that but all I can pull now from another machine is like first 400

also my blablabla/Dropbox/blablabla.git file is smaller than my local

```
/var/www/blablabla/.git
```

so I guess some files aren pushed and so it seems when I've cloned

```
blablabla/Dropbox/blablabla.git
```

from another machine

so how can I properly push now on the first machine so I can pull from the second

I also have branches

plus `git push dropbox` shows `Up to date`

Help?

I think I can put that

```
/var/www/blablabla/.git
```

on dropbox and clone that but what have I did wrong on the first machine plus I want to be able to normally push so it makes changes, this worked some time before (I have some changes but last 100 commits lost)

Comment: Don't use Dropbox for git. Use a dedicated git repository like GitHub or, if you insist on private repos, BitBucket. Git definitely does not lose commits just like that. This is most likely a Dropbox sync issue.

Comment: I've managed to copy that local .git folder onto something.git in Dropbox folder, from there I could pull so I've got the data. I'm thinking something about write permissions or sth I dont know

Answer (score 1):

> my `blablabla/Dropbox/blablabla.git` file is smaller than my local `/var/www/blablabla/.git`

Of course: the first one is a bare repo ([for you want to push to it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24115534/6309)).
The second one is a non-bare repo, with a working tree above it. It can include more [unpacked elements](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1584190/6309) in it.

Using Git with Dropbox is dangerous:

- "[Git with Dropbox Issues](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9030201/6309)"
- "[Dropbox: use bundles](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3633346/6309)" (as [in here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9851166/6309))
- "[Backup a Local Git Repository](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2129286/6309)"

Yes, you cannot push to a bundle, but you can quickly create an [incremental bundle](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26178884/6309) to exchange the latest commits (I mention scripts [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23712022/6309)).

Regarding missing commits, and `git push dropbox` showing "up to date", check that you are currently on a valid branch (`git branch`), and not in a [detached head](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3965714/6309).