# Single-developer Git with Dropbox backups: seeking safe, simple configuration

Tags: git, dropbox

I'd like to use `Git` for a single-developer project, but how do I do backups using Dropbox?

There are actually a number of posts here discussing either `Git` for single-developer work or using `Git` with Dropbox with multiple developers, but the ones I saw did not address the single  biggest concern:

> If Dropbox backs up local  `.git` repository while it is being modified,
> the repository could be left in a nonsensical, unrecoverable state.

To be clear, suppose I have a directory `Working` containing the `git` repository as a subdirectory `.git`. This is my main repository. From `~/Dropbox` a symbolic link points to Working, thus backing up `.git`. I never push or pull anything: everything is local.

If I perform a local `git` commit on `Working`, which thus modifies `.git`, Dropbox might decide at just that moment to backup `.git`. If my machine crashed then, I would have a useless `.git` repository on the Dropbox server: I couldn't recover any files off it.

Answer (score 1):

I always recommended to *not* use DropBox directly with a .git folder content: too many files which can potentially change too many times.

I proposed in "[Backup a Local Git Repository](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2129286/6309)" to use **[`git bundle`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1251717/6309)** instead: that produces only *one* file (which acts as a git repo), and DropBox will have no issue copying it around.