# Use Dropbox for shared Sourcecontrol

Tags: xcode, git, version-control

I want to use source-control in my project and also work from different computers on the same project.
Is it possible to simply use XCODE's "Create local Git-Repository" - function to do this?
The project files could be shared via Dropbox over different computers.
Is that possible or are there any problems to fear with that solution?

Comment: I personnally do not recommend Dropbox as a mean of sharing git repo (http://stackoverflow.com/a/31629250/6309)

Comment: With Dropbox, you can't keep and inspect the history of your codebase, merge changes, etc. Bad idea. Stick with Git (or some proper version-control system).

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid that XCode doesn't support uploading to Dropbox. Please try some vcs like git.