# Remote repo on Google Drive working fine one day, breaks down the next without me touching it

Tags: git, android-studio, remote-repository

So I wanted to make a remote git repository for myself that I can use to work on different machines.
Sounds simple, Google drive offers its sync utility for PC and Mac (I use both) so..
I created a remote repo, pretty much following this guide: https://medium.com/@techstreams/git-google-drive-simple-git-host-3a84db4fc1fd

It worked fine for the first day - I could commit&push on Macbook, see the changes on PC, commit&push on PC and so on.

Need to mention that I use Android Studio mostly and it has VCS built in, so I used that. Everything worked.

The next day I worked only on Mac, when I wanted to get the changes on PC, there was an error saying

> "Can't update: no tracked branch No tracked branch configured for
> branch master."

Note that it worked perfectly well before and the only thing I did on Mac is Commit&push - again just like before when it worked. I didn't touch the Google drive folders in any way etc.

Anyway, after trying different methods I finally fixed this error and everything worked again. A day later the situation repeats itself. Again, I worked on Mac and did Commit&push few times, yesterday PC was getting the changes, today it shows that same error.
And the `git fetch` command shows:

> error: refs/heads/master does not point to a valid object!

Obviously, now the 'git log' inside the remote repo itself also tells that the HEAD object is bad.. duh.

What am I missing with this setup? I mean, it works, I change nothing except repeating actions that worked the previous day - bam! an error.

Comment: What happens when you type `git ststus`? Does `git checkout master` work?

Comment: Do you see the expected download/upload log in both your Google drive clients ? Are you the only one to use this shared folder ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have always advocated against using a "sync drive" (dropbox, Google drive, One Drive, ...) for a *all* Git repository (working tree plus `.git` directory).

If you can, you should push to a [`git bundle`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1251717/6309), which is *one* file.
You can safely have that file in your drive: it will be synchronized without issue, as opposed to the many `.git/` files.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. After a lot of frustration I found out that it indeed had to do with the fact that it's a "sync-drive", I switched to a network NAS which is less comfortable to use, but at least not failing me every day.